# load and "unload" lots of pictures really often in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am working on an application on android which is loaded-images intensive ! according to the position of user, the system loads pictures from the disk (from 5 to 25 jpeg-1000x1000) to display them immediately. 
I would like to have some advices how to do it ! I mean, according to you, what would be the best thread implementation to use (AsynchTask, Thread, Runnable ) ? 
I'm pretty lost and confused about the best method to do it, and differences between asynch-runnable…
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would read the training section here:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

And suggest you take a look at:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
Maybe it solves already your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your picture is heavy (1000x1000), you will maybe meet some problem with old device which have small java heap (memory allocated for active app)
I advise you to reduce the size of your images.

Comment: the phone is rooted ! I have 800 Mo of heap size, so it's ok !